# Is it possible to know the history of a commit in detached mode?

Tags: git, gitlab

our team uses git with self-hosted GitLab, and I am facing a puzzling situation. we migrated our infra from on-prem to the cloud 2 weeks ago, and I am wondering if maybe that could be the reason..

in February 2023, I gave feedback to my team by email, with some links and screenshots, highlighting a commit that I didn't think was correct and should be reverted or fixed.

This is the screenshot I took from my IDE in February 2023, giving feedback on a commit done on Nov 23rd 2022 (the highlighted one).

[image: git history screenshot]

This commit in master branch is the result of a merge request that was merged. GitLab MR overview confirms it :

[image]

the problem is that today (end of March 2023), when I look at the git history in my IDE, I get this :

[image]

- the commits before, on Nov 2nd, 4th and 18th, are visible, no problem.
- **then, 3 commits are missing** : the one I didn't like on Nov 23rd, but also the ones on Feb 1st and Feb 6th.
- but the commit on Feb 10th ("since we have 2 webClients...") is still there

**--> where did the 3 commits in the middle go ?**

Since I have the commit ID from GitLab, I tried to do a checkout - and it is there in my local Git repository, but in detached mode :

[image]

The only explanation I have is that somebody did `push --force` on master branch and rewrote history - which by default is not enabled (master branch is protected).

Is there another reasonable explanation ? is there a way, using some advanced git commands to figure out what happened to this commit :

- was it indeed in master branch at some point ?
- when was it removed ?

could the git/gitLab data migration to the cloud be the root cause ? I would expect the repository to be totally unreadable / corrupted if there had been some issue during the data transfer, not that some commits "in the middle" got lost during the copy.

Comment: First run `git branch --contains=<hash>` to make sure that it isn’t in any branch.

Comment: It looks like a leaf commit in your screenshot. Then someone must have gone back one step (“feat: configure[…]”) and continued from there.

Comment: I ran the command, and the commit  is in no branch. I would also believe someone went one step back and continued from there, but the commit after ("since we have 2 webClients.." ) is still there after...